# Oracle query to resolve column values concatenation

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have three columns in a tables

```
Column names with datatypes
First_week - Number 
Days       - Number
Second_week- Number

Column Values
8
6
11
```

I want to concatenate these values such that result returns  8/6/11
If anyone of the column values are null then the concatenation must be 8/-/11
If all are null then the result must be -/-/-
How can this be achieved in an oracle query?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that you could use `decode`, `nvl` functions or `case` expression. Here is an example of using `decode`:

```
with your_table(First_week, Days, Second_week) as(
  select 8, 6, 11      from dual union all
  select 5, null, 12   from dual union all
  select null, 7, null from dual union all
  select null, null, null from dual
  )
select decode(to_char(First_week), null, '-', to_char(First_week)) || '/' ||
       decode(to_char(Days), null, '-', to_char(Days))             || '/' ||
       decode(to_char(Second_week), null, '-', to_char(Second_week)) as result
  from your_table


RESULT
---------
8/6/11
5/-/12
-/7/-
-/-/-
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php

"In Oracle/PLSQL, the coalesce function returns the first non-null expression in the list. If all expressions evaluate to null, then the coalesce function will return null."

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm#i997789

"|| Concatenates character strings and CLOB data."

Now we have all the building blocks to write something like:

COALESCE(First_week, '-') || '/' || COALESCE(Days, '-') || '/' || COALESCE(Second_week, '-')

Answer (score 1):

What About This

```
SELECT    NVL (TO_CHAR (FIRST_WEEK), '-')
       || '/'
       || NVL (TO_CHAR (DAYS), '-')
       || '/'
       || NVL (TO_CHAR (SECOND_WEEK), '-')
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```